# Why does the first button pressed shrink in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I am a novice programmer working on a project that has buttons change color when pressed (among other things).  I am having a problem that the first button I click shrinks (the padding increases?) when it is clicked, but it still works and does everything it is supposed to.  I have tried looking through theme.res to find a way to stop the button from shrinking when pressed and I have tried looking for an answer online, but have not found a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Check the selected/unselected & pressed styles have similar settings for margin/padding/font & border

Comment: See https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorial-theming-basics.html

Answer (score 1):

In the Resource Editor(theme.res), go to "Themes" -> "Unselected" tab. Right click over the style you use for the button and press Derive All.